# How much air, by mass, enters an average CFM56 turbofan engine cruising per minute?

Tags: jet-engine

How many kg of air enters an average CFM56 turbofan engine cruising per minute?

I have looked everywhere and cannot find it or figure out how to find it, if you could either tell me or give advice on where or how to find it I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: A reasonable first approximation would be the mass of air that the engine flies through in a minute - i.e. frontal area of the fan blades $\times$ aircraft velocity $\times$ air density. As a sanity check on your estimate, though at different conditions where the inlet velocity is *not* equal to the aircraft speed, at takeoff each engine on a B747 generates about 200kN of thrust, with an air mass flow of about 1 tonne (1000kg) per second.

Comment: Aviation.SE is the right place to ask this.

Comment: @alephzero Please don't post answers in comments.

Comment: When you say "how much" do you mean by mass or by volume?

Comment: @TomMcw It was originally kg but someone altered it

Comment: @SRawes Put that back in :)

Answer (score 7):

**Airflow at takeoff**

The [CFM56-5C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56#CFM56-5C_series), the largest CFM56, powers A340. Its thrust is about 145 kN at takeoff. It has an air mass flow of 485 kg/s ([source](http://www.iasg.co.uk/pdfs/articles/engine_services/Pages%20from%20JULY%20CVR.pdf)). A A340 has four engines.

[image]
<sup>CFM56-5C, [source](http://www.safran-aircraft-engines.com/media/lufthansa-cfm56-5c-engine-achieves-100000-flight-hours-20161108).</sup>

Fortunately this thrust is not needed after takeoff and the engine airflow is considerably lower in cruise. I don't have the actual figure but we can do a quick estimate using the fuel consumption. It can be assumed relatively safely that air is in proportion of fuel.

**Fuel consumption**

According to [this document](http://webserver.dmt.upm.es/%7Eisidoro/bk3/c17/Aerospace%20engine%20data.pdf), for the CFM56-5C:

- T/O thrust is 150 kN, fuel consumption 2.3 kg/s
- Cruise thrust is 40 kN, fuel 0.5 kg/s.

(meaning cruise at 27% T/O thrust requires 22% of the T/O fuel, the engine is more efficient in altitude.)

**Airflow in cruise**

So we can roughly estimate air mass flow in cruise to be about 485 * 0.22 = 107 kg/s.

This is supported by figures found online in non authoritative sources, like page 245 of [this book](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Aircraft_Propulsion_and_Gas_Turbine_Engi.html?id=oGPLBQAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y):

[image]

**Bypass flow vs core flow**

After the fan, air is separated in two flows: core (hot/primary) and bypass (cold/secondary) according to the bypass ratio.

The CFM56-5C bypass ratio is 6.4:1. So:

- The part used in the core for combustion, bleed air and core cooling is 485/7.4 = 66 kg/s
- The part bypassing the core, and providing only thrust by fan acceleration is 419 kg/s.

---

For comparison the Trent XWB (A350 XWB), a larger engine developing 430 kN at takeoff, has an air mass flow of 1,440 kg/s ([source](http://newatlas.com/rolls-royce-trent-xwb-engine-a350-xwb/32133/)).

Comment: will that not be different at a cruising altitude @mins

Comment: Is this figure the amount passing through the intake, or the amount passing through the combustion chamber?  Can you break down the two for a feel for how much air is bypassed?

Comment: @SRawes: Yes, this is the maximum thrust/airflow. I have updated the answer.

Comment: The specific fuel consumption at cruise you give is suspect. The *thrust*-specific fuel consumption of high-bypass turbofans should increase with speed. [This table](http://www.jet-engine.net/civtfspec.html) gives $33.7\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{Nh}}$ static and $55.6\ \frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{Nh}}$ at cruise. The *power*-specific fuel consumption still decreases, so propulsive efficiency increases, but 27% thrust for 22% fuel seems wrong.

Comment: @JanHudec: Thanks for the remark. The different sources I use are obviously not related to the same CFM56-5C customer version. However, the variations are not either extremely large, and the approximation seems to be still correct. So except for the 27% vs. 22% non essential comment, I believe air quantities shown 485/107 kg/s are correct (I'll update them if someone can point me to complete CFM56-5C specifications).

Comment: @mins, I would really love to see a (more) complete specification of the engine too (I would like to improve the rather poor simulation that flightgear uses), but so far never seen it.